# How to deal with noexcept in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, noexcept

I'm trying to create a custom exception that derives from `std::exception` and overrides `what()`. At first, I wrote it like this:

```
class UserException : public std::exception
{
private:
    const std::string message;
public:
    UserException(const std::string &message)
        : message(message)
    {}

    virtual const char* what() const override
    {
        return message.c_str();
    }
};
```

This works fine in VS2012, but it doesn't compile in GCC 4.8 with `-std=c++11`:

> error: looser throw specifier for ‘virtual const char* UserException::what() const’

So I add `noexcept`:

```
virtual const char* what() const noexcept override
```

This works fine in GCC, but it doesn't compile in Visual Studio (because VS 2012 doesn't support `noexcept`):

> error C3646: 'noexcept' : unknown override specifier

What is the recommended way to deal with this? I want the same code to compile with both compilers and I'm using C++11 features, so I can't compile with different `-std`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use a macro

```
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#define NOEXCEPT noexcept
#else
#define NOEXCEPT
#endif
```

And then define the function as

```
virtual const char* what() const NOEXCEPT override
```

You could also modify that to allow `noexcept` on later versions of VS by checking the value of `_MSC_VER`; for VS2012 the value is 1600.

Comment: According to [this video (look at the table at 58:00)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/2-306), `noexcept` won't be supported in VS2013.

Comment: Also, does it make sense to use `#define NOEXCEPT throw()` for the VS version?

Comment: @svick There is a small difference in behavior between the two. Throwing from a function marked `throw()` will call `std::unexpected`, whereas `std::terminate` will be called if it were marked `noexcept`; but in your use case the two should be equivalent. However, the [MSDN page for `std::exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4ts6d5a.aspx) doesn't indicate `what()` is marked `throw()`, so you may run into warnings or errors if you add the exception specification to the overriden function.

Answer (score 16):

"noexcept" is only supported since the Visual Studio 2015 (as stated here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfa0edys.aspx).
I have used following code with Visual Studio 2013 (derived from above examples):

```
#if !defined(HAS_NOEXCEPT)
#if defined(__clang__)
#if __has_feature(cxx_noexcept)
#define HAS_NOEXCEPT
#endif
#else
#if defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__) && __GNUC__ * 10 + __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 46 || \
    defined(_MSC_FULL_VER) && _MSC_FULL_VER >= 190023026
#define HAS_NOEXCEPT
#endif
#endif

#ifdef HAS_NOEXCEPT
#define NOEXCEPT noexcept
#else
#define NOEXCEPT
#endif
```

Comment: Create some header file, include it where you plan to use all that.

Answer (score 12):

This check works to see if `noexcept` is supported:

```
// Is noexcept supported?
#if defined(__clang__) && __has_feature(cxx_noexcept) || \
    defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__) && __GNUC__ * 10 + __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 46 || \
    defined(_MSC_FULL_VER) && _MSC_FULL_VER >= 180021114
#  define NOEXCEPT noexcept
#else
#  define NOEXCEPT
#endif
```

The above works with Clang, GCC and MSVC.

Comment: Well, MSVC 2010 doesn't have `noexcept`, does it? Its `_MSC_VER` is `1600`, which is smaller than `1800`, therefore `NOEXCEPT` should expand to nothing. What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: `warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline`. It looks like ` __has_feature(cxx_noexcept)` is confusing it for some reason. When I remove that it works fine. Edit: I realize now I was treating warnings as errors, and this was just a warning. If I suppress 4067 it works after all.

Comment: 180021114 seems to be VS2013, which does not support `noexcept`. ivan.ukr's value of 190023026 works better for me.

Answer (score 10):

use `BOOST_NOEXCEPT` in `<boost/config.hpp>`

The boost config library was designed for compatibility issues like this. According to [the doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_describe_c__11_features_not_supported):

> If `BOOST_NO_CXX11_NOEXCEPT` is defined (i.e. C++03 compliant compilers) these macros are defined as:
>
> ```
>     #define BOOST_NOEXCEPT
>     #define BOOST_NOEXCEPT_OR_NOTHROW throw()
>     #define BOOST_NOEXCEPT_IF(Predicate)
>     #define BOOST_NOEXCEPT_EXPR(Expression) false
> ```
>
> If `BOOST_NO_CXX11_NOEXCEPT` is not defined (i.e. C++11 compliant compilers) they are defined as:
>
> ```
>     #define BOOST_NOEXCEPT noexcept
>     #define BOOST_NOEXCEPT_OR_NOTHROW noexcept
>     #define BOOST_NOEXCEPT_IF(Predicate) noexcept((Predicate))
>     #define BOOST_NOEXCEPT_EXPR(Expression) noexcept((Expression))
> ```

Many of the other answers here have a similar implementation but this library is cleaner, better tested, and will do the right thing when your compiler is upgraded. I recommend looking at the boost config library in general for other features, especially in this time of language flux and varying levels of support among compilers.

Answer (score 3):

The **noexcept** is one of the easiest "lacks" of MSVC to deal with: Just use the macro `_NOEXCEPT` which under MSVC2013 is defined in yvals.h .

Comment: But I wasn't looking for a solution that works only in VS, I was looking for a solution that works everywhere (or at least both in VS and GCC).

Comment: **facepalm** Well @svick then use the macro I just gave you and combine it with the `noexcept` from C++11 and voilà you'll have a solution that works everywhere! :D

Answer (score 3):

Add the following lines in your code in Visual Studio:

```
#ifdef _NOEXCEPT
#define noexcept _NOEXCEPT
#endif
```

Comment: This is wrong. You are defining a macro with the same literal as a reserved keyword, which is forbidden.

Comment: This works in VS to introduce compatibility between two versions.

Comment: Even in Visual Studio versions before C++11, noexcept is a reserved keyword. You'll get a warning during compilation. I suggest to use capital NOEXCEPT in this case.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to define _NOEXCEPT to noexcept if it's undefined? (So you'd use VS's version when compiling in MSVC and C++11's version in other compilers.)

Answer (score 3):

What I've recently used is following:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define NOEXCEPT _NOEXCEPT
#else
#define NOEXCEPT noexcept
#endif
```

and then just use `NOEXCEPT` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the old `throw()` (deprecated in C++11) works in both compilers. So I changed the code to:

```
virtual const char* what() const throw() override
```

Comment: But that is not the same thing. Does it remove the `looser throw specifier for ‘virtual const char* UserException::what() const’` error?

Comment: @VáclavZeman Yeah, as far as I remember, this actually worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The other way to go around is create header file and include it if necessary in your source code that should be compile by gcc, vc,or clang.

### no_except_work_around.h

```
#ifndef no_except_work_around_H
#define no_except_work_around_H

#if (_MSC_VER <= 1800)
#include <xkeycheck.h>
#define noexcept
#endif 

#endif //no_except_work_around_H
```

=====================================================

P.S> doesn't cover case 
noexcept(false)
but works fine for VC2010,2012,2013, gcc 4.9

Comment: The advantage you can start use noexcept and after moving on VC 2015 just remove header in your code without impact:

#include "no_except_work_around.h"

Answer (score 0):

`#IF`s may work, even if a bit hacky.

You could just do this:

```
#if __GNUG__
virtual const char* what() const noexcept override
#else
virtual const char* what() const override
#endif
//method body
```

Answer (score 0):

add the below path to the additional include directories

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include
```

at this location there is file called "yvals.h" which contain definition of _NOEXCEPT