How to do C++ Contracts such that compilers can use once support comes for this (such as `float f(X *x)[[expects:x]]` or `f(X *x) [[ensures: x->u]])`?
Must you use a macro to wrap this (plus hope whoever uses your code years later knows to pass -D USE_CONTRACTS,) such as
/* Licenses: allows all uses ("Creative Commons"/"Apache 2") */
#ifndef INCLUDE_GUARD_cxx_Macros_hxx
#define INCLUDE_GUARD_cxx_Macros_hxx
/* Miscellaneous macros */
#include <assert.h> /* assert static_assert */
#include <stdbool.h> /* false */
#include <version> /* __cpp_lib_unreachable */ /* [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test] */
namespace Susuwu { /* namespaces do not affect macros. Is just standard practice to wrap all of a project's contents with namespaces. */
#define GLUE(S, U) S##U /* concatanates 2 constants */

/* `UNREACHABLE` is close to `ASSUME(false)` */
#if (!defined NDEBUG) && (defined static_assert)
/* [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249282/c-c-portable-way-to-detect-debug-release] [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290509/debug-vs-ndebug] */
/* Debug: Promises unreachable, for static analysis */
#   define UNREACHABLE static_assert(false)
#elif (!defined NDEBUG)
#   define UNREACHABLE assert(false)
#elif __cpp_lib_unreachable
/* Release: Promises executable can not reach this spot, for compiler which optimizes this. Warning: `UNREACHABLE && UB (undefined behaviour)` */
#include <utility> /* std::unreachable() */
#   define UNREACHABLE std::unreachable()
#elif (defined __GNUC__) && ((4 <= __GNUC__ && 4 < __GNUC_MINOR__) || 4 < __GNUC__) /* `~ $ g++` */
#   define UNREACHABLE __builtin_unreachable()
#else /* else (!def NDEBUG) && (!supports unreachable) */
#   define UNREACHABLE /* No-op */
#endif /* __cpp_lib_unreachable elif IS_GCC ...*/

#ifdef USE_CONTRACTS /* Pass `-D USE_CONTRACTS` once compiler has C++26 (Contracts) */
/* `EXPECTS(X)` is close to `@pre @code X @endcode` or `ASSUME(X)` but is for headers; https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2521r2.html */
/* Promises `(true == (X))`, for static analysis, or for compiler which optimizes this. Warning: `if(!(X)) {UB (undefined behaviour)}` */
#   define EXPECTS(X) [[expects: X]] /* Usage: `void pushf(std::deque<float> &x, float f) EXPECTS(!x.full());` */
#   define ENSURES(X) [[ensures: X]] /* Usage: `void pushf(std::deque<float> &x, float f) ENSURES(0 != x.size());` */
#else /* else !def USE_CONTRACTS */
#   define EXPECTS(X) /* `@pre @code X @endcode` */
#   define ENSURES(X) /* `@post @code X @encode` */
#endif /* else !def USE_CONTRACTS */

/* `ASSUME(X)` is close to `@pre @code X @endcode` or `[[expects: x]]` */
/* TODO: choose best of [various possible ASSUME macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054078/how-to-guide-gcc-optimizations-based-on-assertions-without-runtime-cost) */
#ifndef NDEBUG
/* Debug: Promises `(true == (X))`, for static analysis */
#   define ASSUME(X) assert(X)
#elif (!defined USE_ASSUME) || USE_ASSUME /* Default: if(!NDEBUG) USE_ASSUME=true; pass `-D USE_ASSUME=false` to disable this */ 
/* Release: Promises `(true == (X))`, for compiler which optimizes this. Warning: `if(!(X)) {UB (undefined behaviour)}` */
#   ifdef IS_MSVC
#       define ASSUME(X) __assume(X)
#   elif __clang__ /* `~ $ clang++` */
#       define ASSUME(X) __builtin_assume(X)
#   else /* (!def IS_MSVC) && (!def __clang__) */
#       define ASSUME(X) (static_cast<void>(X) || UNREACHABLE)
#   endif /* !def IS_MSVC */
#else /* !def USE_ASSUME */
#   define ASSUME(X)
#endif /* !def USE_ASSUME */

#if defined(__clang__) && __has_feature(cxx_noexcept) || defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__) && __GNUC__ * 10 + __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 46 || defined(_MSC_FULL_VER) && _MSC_FULL_VER >= 180021114 /* [Other `noexcept` tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387640/how-to-deal-with-noexcept-in-visual-studio) */
#   define NOEXCEPT noexcept /* Usage: `void versionInfo() NOEXCEPT;` is close to `void versionInfo() [[ensures: true]];` or `versionInfo(); !UNREACHABLE;*/
#endif /* supports noexcept */
#if (defined __has_cpp_attribute) && __has_cpp_attribute(noreturn) /* TODO: [Cmake test for `\[\[noreturn\]\]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33517293/24473928) */
#   define NORETURN [[noreturn]] /* Usage: `NORETURN void exit();` is close to `void exit() [[ensures:: false]];` or `exit(); UNREACHABLE;*/
#endif /* supports [[noreturn]] */
}; /* namespace Susuwu */
#endif /* ndef INCLUDE_GUARD_cxx_Macros_hxx */

?
Thought that Contract's attribute syntax was close to #pragma (such that compilers without support would ignore this,)
but [[expects: cns.isInitialized()]]; gives error: expected ','
How to just ignore this (as unimplemented #pragma X does)?
Does a future flag exist (#ifdef FUTURE_FLAG_FOR_CONTRACTS) such that is not required to pass -D USE_CONTRACTS to g++?
Contracts references shows that since C++20 the syntax was as above (draft authors just argue about corner cases of what the compiler should do with Contracts):
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2388r4.html
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2521r2.html
https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6702
Termux g++ errors

The committee hasn't agreed on a syntax for C++26 contracts yet, so there's no way.

I think the actual general question is, how to write the code which involves a syntactic structure from future standards in a way such that it can both utilize the feature correctly if compiled with a new compiler, and also fallback to nothing if compiled with an old compiler. The contract is just an example. Are macros the only way?

@WeijunZhou How certain are you that you have 100% certainly guessed the syntax of the new standard?  Does using feature macros count as using macros?  __cpp_contracts is likely to be the feature flag for contracts: you could guess it will be and put your code behind it, but if you got the syntax wrong you'll break hard. (and if you got the feature flag wrong, you'll silently not turn on when contracts arrive).  You could guess what standard contracts show up at and test on that?

I guess I would just conditionally define my macro and use that everywhere. The macro definition should be put in something like config.h and that file should be included by every file in the tree. As for the issue of guessing the whole syntax wrong... Maybe there's not much I can do besides testing possible syntaxes as you suggested.
